# How to update slice of struct in recursive fashion

Tags: go, recursion, struct, slice

For following code, I'm expecting output of `{"NewName" [{"NewName" []}]}` but it's not updating child structs. How can we make sure it updates every struct in hierarchy.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type red struct {
    Name string
    Child []red
}

func (r *red) setName(nameString string){
    r.Name = nameString
    for _, child := range r.Child{
        child.setName(nameString)
    }
}

func main() {
    obj := red{Name:"NameA",Child:[]red{red{Name: "NameB"}}}
    fmt.Print(obj)
    fmt.Print("\n")

    obj.setName("NewName")
    //Expectation {"NewName" [{"NewName" []}]}
    fmt.Print(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not to use pointers everywhere as suggested by others answers.

The problem in your code is that when you iterate the child, you get a value by copy for each item, you then set the name on the copy.

But as you do not copy back the modified value into the slice, the changes are not retained.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type red struct {
    Name  string
    Child []red
}

func (r *red) setName(s string) {
    r.Name = s
    for i, ch := range r.Child {
        ch.setName(s) // ch is not a ptr to r.Child[i], it is a value copy
        r.Child[i] = ch // so you must re assign the copy into the slice!
    }
}

func main() {
    obj := red{Name: "A", Child: []red{red{Name: "B"}}}
    fmt.Print(obj)
    fmt.Print("\n")

    obj.setName("X")
    //Expectation {X [{X []}]}
    fmt.Print(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `Child` be `[]*red` instead of `[]red` to prevent copies of red being created.

See the following tweaks(the `String` method is just to make the output look pretty, else we'll get memory addresses printed):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type red struct {
    Name  string
    Child []*red
}

func (r *red) String() string {
    ret := fmt.Sprintf("{%s [", r.Name)
    for _, c := range r.Child {
        ret = ret + c.Name + " "
    }
    ret += "]}"
    return ret
}

func (r *red) setName(s string) {
    r.Name = s
    for _, ch := range r.Child {
        ch.setName(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    obj := red{Name: "A", Child: []*red{&red{Name: "B"}}}
    fmt.Print(obj)
    fmt.Print("\n")

    obj.setName("X")
    //Expectation {X [{X []}]}
    fmt.Print(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing `Child []red` to a list of pointers: `Child []*red`.

Here's the full code in [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yPqq1yIxGwa)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type red struct {
    Name string
    Child []*red
}

func (r *red) setName(s string){
    r.Name = s
    for _, ch := range r.Child{
        ch.setName(s)
    }
}

func main() {
    obj := red{Name:"A",Child:[]*red{&red{Name: "B"}}}
    fmt.Println(obj.Name)
    for _, ch := range obj.Child{
       fmt.Println(ch.Name)
    }
    fmt.Print("\n")

    obj.setName("X")
    //Expectation X \n X
    fmt.Println(obj.Name)
    for _, ch := range obj.Child{
       fmt.Println(ch.Name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is here

```
for _, ch := range r.Child{
        ch.setName(s)
}
```

You are updating using `ch` which is not updating you `r.Child` slice actually. Your code is equivalent like this

```
var ch red
for i, _:= range r.Child{
    ch = r.Child[i]
    ch.setName(s)
}
```

To solve this you can update the slice this way.

```
for i, _ := range r.Child {
    r.Child[i].setName(s) // access the slice eliment by index and update
}
```

And it's a good pattern to use `[]*red` for child.